# False boolean is stopping script from being used more than once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm putting together an examination system for a game I'm working on and I have it working as intended, although part of the script will only work for one gameObject. When the held boolean is true I want the player's control to be off and turn it back on when it's false. The problem is, it's always false, so when I try to pick up another object it won't stop the player's control.

I'm assuming this is because it's running in the Update function. I tried to put them into their own functions and call the functions when the bool is true/false but I get the same result.

I've also written another script before that toggled on/off the player's control but that was done with two single mouse inputs and it worked as expected.

I have a script that handles the raycast interactions and will toggle the held boolean on/off. While the raycast is touching, the object's script becomes activated and turned null if it's not touching. The object's script is like this..

```
void Update()
{
    if (held == true)
    {
        thisObject.transform.position = holdPos.position;
        //transform.rotation = holdPos.rotation;
        lockLook.Control.Toggle = false;
        movelock.Control.Toggle = false;
    }
    else
    {
        thisObject.transform.position = startPos;
        thisObject.transform.rotation = startRot;
        lockLook.Control.Toggle = true;
        movelock.Control.Toggle = true;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming I need to find a way to only call the false boolean once.

Comment: Put at any of the routines you want "turned off" `if (!held) return;` in all of them

Comment: Could you elaborate? I've tried to put it in a few places. Thanks.

Comment: im not sure how you could elborate more, all the functions you dont want working put that as the first line

Comment: Yes, putting it as the first line of the function stops it from working... but that's not what I need. I need to toggle the control back and then stop it.

Comment: So for that one function, decide if it should be doing it or not near the front and if yes, do, else stop